# Communication between two flask services in Docker

Tags: python, networking, docker, flask, request

I have two Flask apps, each in separate container. I would like to call app A from app B. At the moment I can do that only by hard-coding IP of the app A like this:

```
@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    r = requests.get('http://172.18.0.1:5000')
    return r.text
```

Is there a simple way of making calls using containers aliases? What would be recommended solution of such problem i.e. two services that communicate with each other?

I am new to docker and I am not sure what should I look for, so any resources/links would be very appreciated.

Comment: Change the URL for your requests into a variable, preferably one loaded from a config file. Configure it as a hostname. Run the containers with `docker run --name hostname`

Answer (score 1):

Firstly it's very recommended to use `hostname`instead of IP.
But... why? Ip could change every time and it's very annoying to check over and over what IP has the app but the `hostname` changes only if you want to.

Then:

```
cd path/to/dockerfile
docker build -t your_repo/image_name .    
docker run -d  -p 6000:5000 image_name --name hostname
```

And you app.py (just a name) should be like this:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    r = requests.get('http://hostname:5000')
    return r.text

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

Notice that I'm using host ['0.0.0.0'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.0.0.0) cause you may experience some problems trying to connect both containers.

Hope that's enough for you to fix the issue.

Have a nice day!

Comment: Hi, 

Thank you for your answer. It has not fully solved my problems. Doing request on 'hostname' leads to `requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL 'host': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://host?`
If I will do `http://host:6000` I get max re-tries exception. Obviously I am doing something wrong. Any ideas? I find networking quite confusing because docker is evolving so fast - quite hard to grasp what is current workflow.

Comment: Hi! Yes, I was wrong, already fixed, thanks!
About your issue, you should use 5000, not 6000, else it's gonna fail.
Basically, if you see the docker run command, is mapping the 6000 port in your host machine to 5000 to your docker container.

Try with ``http://host:5000``

Comment: Hi, I am already confused. If I do: `docker run -d -p 5002:5000 externall3 
` and externall3 image is ` 
@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
      return 'b'
` I can access it at port 5002. Am I right in thinking that -p  does external port: port within container? 
Either way it (`http://host:5000`) didn't work.

Comment: I am confused as to using link? Is it still valid way of connecting containers? Don't have to do something link --link hostname:hostname?

Comment: here you can see the full description about linking containers:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/dockerlinks/#/communication-across-links
BTW, I'd be great if you've some gist or GitHub repo to see your code or at least the commands.
:)

Comment: If using docker compose, the `hostname` in `'http://hostname:5000'` would be the service's name that was specified in docker-compose.yml